# java system.out.println behavior

Tags: java

```
String s1="bool";
String s2="bool";
System.out.println((s1==s2)+" bool");
System.out.println(s1==s2+" bool");
```

Can you help me why are different output.

Comment: Please be aware that comparing strings via `==` in Java is only deterministically safe if you want to see whether two strings are the exact same object.  In rare cases, the two strings can have the same value and be different objects.  None of the answers are pointing this out, but it is likely that the correct thing to do is compare via .equals(), i.e., s1.equals(s2) which checks whether the two strings have the same value, regardless of whether they are the same object.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that operator `+` has precedence over operator `==` (check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). SO in the second case, you are first computing a string addition resulting on "bool bool" and then comparing it to S1.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, you have 2 string compared, then `" bool"` appended.

In the second scenario, you have `" bool"` appended to `s2` first.

Here it is in expanded form:

1.

```
boolean b = s1==s2;
String result = b + " bool";
```

2.

```
String s = s2 + " bool";
boolean result = s1 == s;
```

To learn more about **Order of operations in Java**, visit [**This link.**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: Why downvoting my answer? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this without saying why? is it because they want their answers displayed before mine?

Comment: i want to ask why its output  true bool false why not it print true bool in second case . why it print only false not true

Comment: @SatishSahu Because in the second scenario, the strings are added first, then the comparison happens. So what happens is that it checks: `"bool" == "bool bool"`

Answer (score 1):

In first case `(s1==s2) + " bool"`:

- `(s1 == s2)` evaluates to true (since both are String literals).
- `true + "bool"` this is a concatenation, where `true` is converted to `"true"` then it's appended to `" bool"`. The result is `"true bool"`.

In second case `s1==s2+" bool"`:

- `+` has higher priority than `==`, thus `s2+" bool"` evaluates first to `"boolbool"`.
- Now, `s1 == "boolbool"` is evaluated which obviously evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line `(s1==s2)+" bool"`, you are explicitly comparing `s1` to `s2` **first** (by putting parenthesis around the expression) and adding `bool` to the result. This will compare `s1` to `s2`, or `bool` == `bool` and then add the String `bool` to the resultant boolean expression.

In the second line,  there are no parenthesis around the comparison expression and therefore the plus operation happens **before** the comparison. Based on the rules of Java, it will evaluated as if written as `s1== (s2+" bool")`. This will compare `s2 + " bool"` or `bool bool`, to `s1`, `bool`.

In short, the first expression will result in a String,  while the second, will result in a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(s1==s2+" bool");
```

Concatenation, `+`, takes precedence over comparison, `==`, so *concatenation* evaluates first.

---

```
System.out.println((s1==s2)+" bool");
```

Grouping, `()`, takes precedence over concatenation, `+`, so *comparison* evaluates first.

Answer (score 1):

More visual notation is:

```
System.out.println((s1 == s2) + " bool");
System.out.println(s1 == (s2+" bool"));
```

**Important note:** strings must be compared with `equals` method:

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the parenthesis to control the order of operation, this

```
System.out.println(s1 == s2 + " bool");
```

Evaluates like

```
System.out.println(s1 == (s2 + " bool"));
```

And thus you get `false`. One way to mitigate this type of issue is to use [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Something like

```
System.out.printf("%b bool%n", s1 == s2); // <-- %b is for a boolean
```

Of course, it would behave the same way if `s1` and `s2` were primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

```
(s1==s2) +" bool"
```

checks for s1 ansd s2 are same. If it's same or not same , it would print the result (*in our case it's `true`*) plus the string `bool`

```
s1==s2 + " bool"
```

check for`s1` and `s2+bool` are same (ie, `bool` == `bool bool`). In our case, it's false.